# SQL Server 2008 R2 cannot connect to database engine

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I recently started developing ASP.NET windows application and web sites using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Visual Studio 2010 seems to work fine but I got problem starting SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I open SQL Server Management Studio, the "Connect to Server" window opens and ask me Server Name. Authentication type is "Windows Authentication".

I googled it too much but still cant find suitable server name.
My default instance is `SQLEXPRESS` (I found it in SQL Server Configuration Manager).

I tried `.`, `(local)`, `127.0.0.1`, `localhost`, my machine name (i.e. `MYName-PC/MyName`) but I get error that cannot connect to `(local)` and so on...

When I conncect first time with (local) I got successful connection.
But from next day the error again occured.

When I use server name as `./SQLEXPRESS` I got error that

> The RPC server is not available

I tried using turn my firewall off still no success.

I am very frustrated at this moment because I am not able to find suitable server name.

Thank you for reading my post.

Hope someone will help me.

Thanks.

Comment: did u tried to restart the sql server service ?

Comment: I dont know how to restart the sql service. please help me.

Comment: Thanks Elie.M I figured to find out how to restart sql service. I restarted it and connect as (local). it works!!!

Comment: Go to control panel --> Administrative Tools --> Services --> sql server (SQLEXPRESS).  check the status of the service ... if it not "Running" then u need to right click on and click start ... else try to restart the service.

Comment: Welcome Omkar :) please mark my comment as useful

Comment: Yeah I did it and it works, Thanks very much for your help

Comment: OMG I am again ran in problem. how do i mark your answer as useful? please help me.

Comment: What problem ? the service is down again ? 
And to mark an comment as useful .. put the cursor on the left of the useful comment .. an up arrow will show .. click it :)